# Implementing dplyr's filter() to show multiple entries across a number of years

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sample data set:

```
df <- tibble(
  "PLAYER" = c("Corey Kluber", "CLayton Kershaw", "Max Scherzer", "Chris Sale",
           "Corey Kluber", "Jake Arrieta", "Jose Urena", "Yu Darvish"),
  "YEAR" = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017),
  "WHIP" = c(1.24, 1.50, 1.70, 1.35, 1.42, 1.33, 1.61, 1.10)
 )
```

The real data set goes from 2000 to 2017. How do I use `filter()` (or `dplyr` in general), to bring up all of the players that are active in multiple seasons? For example, in the sample set above, Corey Kluber comes up in 2016 and 2017. How do I use the `dplyr` package to bring him up? I imagine it is something like so:

```
df %>%
  select(PLAYER, YEAR, WHIP) %>%  #MY SET HAS MORE VARIABLES THAN THE SAMPLE SHOWS
  filter(PLAYER %in% YEAR == c(2016,2017))
```

This just returns `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`, when I would want `Corey Kluber` to come up twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use `dplyr::n_distinct` to find out how many times a player appeared in different `session/year`. You have to group on `PLAYER` and then filter data using condition `n_distinct(YEAR)>1`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(PLAYER) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(YEAR) > 1) # A player has appeared in many sessions

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups: PLAYER [1]
#   PLAYER        YEAR  WHIP
#   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Corey Kluber  2016  1.24
# 2 Corey Kluber  2017  1.42
#
```

If `OP` is interested in knowing just name of such players then

```
df %>% group_by(PLAYER) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(YEAR) > 1) %>%
  select(PLAYER) %>%
  distinct()
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
# # Groups: PLAYER [1]
# PLAYER      
# <chr>       
# 1 Corey Kluber
```

Comment: The whole point of my data set (thank you for your answer on my earlier question), is to track the MLB WHIP stat over time, or to see how a pitcher's WHIP changes as he gets older. So this is very very helpful, I'm grateful, thank you